# When N is a poisson distribution

Tags: probability

I have a quick question.

Given that $N$~$Po(\mu)$, $\mu > 0$,  what is $E(S_{N})$ and $Var(S_{N})$, such that $S_{N}$ = $X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{N}$, suppose $X_{i}$ is i.i.d. and independent of N.
$E(X_{i})$ = c and $Var(X_{i})$ = d, where $c$ and $d$ are constants.

From my working,

$E(S_{N})$ = $E(X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{N})$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{N} E(X_{i})$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{N} c$ =  $c \cdot E(N)$ (I think this step have some issues) = $c \cdot \mu$

Similar working for variance.

I feel that this working some issue, the step above, and also shouldn't N be a natural number?
Can anyone correct my working.

Thanks.

Comment: Both your instincts are correct, but don't let the second one (to be wary of "working some issue") scare you away from the first (to take expectations). 
 Use nested conditional expectations.  $ES_N = E ( E(S_N|N))  = \sum_{n\ge0} P(N=n) E(S_n)$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The law of total expectation states that $$\operatorname{E}[S_N] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[S_N \mid N]],$$ and the law of total variance states $$\operatorname{Var}[S_N] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[S_N \mid N]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[S_N \mid N]].$$  When $S_N = X_1 + \cdots + X_N$, that is to say, $S_N$ is the sum of $N$ iid random variables, then the law of total expectation plus linearity of expectation gives $$\operatorname{E}[S_N] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X_1 + \cdots + X_N \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X_1] + \cdots + \operatorname{E}[X_N]] = \operatorname{E}[N \operatorname{E}[X]] = \operatorname{E}[N]\operatorname{E}[X],$$ where $X_i \sim X$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$ is the common distribution of the $X_i$s.  Note that in this case the $X_i$s need not be independent, only identically distributed, because linearity of expectation $$\operatorname{E}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] = \operatorname{E}[X_1] + \cdots + \operatorname{E}[X_n] $$ does not require iid (but the subsequent reduction to $n \operatorname{E}[X]$ does require each expectation $\operatorname{E}[X_i]$ to be equal).

For the total variance, we already know from the above that the conditional expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[S_N \mid N] = N \operatorname{E}[X].$$  The conditional variance **does** require the iid property:  $$\operatorname{Var}[S_N \mid N] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}[X_N] = N \operatorname{Var}[X]$$ since if independence is not satisfied, you would have nonzero covariance terms.  Then $$\operatorname{Var}[S_N] = \operatorname{E}[N]\operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[N \operatorname{E}[X]] = \operatorname{E}[N] \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2 \operatorname{Var}[N].$$

In the case that $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, we have $\operatorname{E}[N] = \operatorname{Var}[N] = \lambda$, thus the above further simplifies to $$\operatorname{E}[S_N] = \lambda \mu, \\ \operatorname{Var}[S_N] = \lambda(\sigma^2 + \mu^2),$$ where $\mu = \operatorname{E}[X]$ and $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[X]$.